# Effect Of deleting trace files?

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

I have an oracle 11G instance. Its trace file are increasing day by day and causing a disk space issue. I have to delete it manually on every disk space alert. I use the command:

```
**find \`pwd\` \\( -name \\*.trc -o -name \\*.trm \\) -mtime +2 -exec rm -rf {} \;**
```

I can schedule this also in cronjob, but I want to know what it will effect in deleting these files and why these files are increasing so much in size. How can I reduce these file by increasing and what will this effect in our database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is the database generating a bunch of trace files?  A trace file would either indicate an error, in which case you would generally need to examine the trace file to determine what the error is and how to correct it, or it would indicate that someone enabled tracing for a session in order to debug an issue, in which case you would want to retain the trace file so that you can do that debugging.  Deleting trace files without looking at them means that you are almost certainly ignoring a symptom of a problem that has the potential to get worse over time.  If this is a real production database rather than a toy database on your local machine, I would strongly suggest determining why the trace files are getting created in the first place and addressing whatever issue(s) are causing the trace files to be created.

Comment: SQL> show parameters 'trace_enabled'; FOUND its true.. Is it ok ?

Comment: @NiteshKumar - That is perfectly normal.  You don't want to disable Oracle's ability to generate trace files when it encounters an issue.

Comment: I am continuously getting below error : ** 2012-11-26 15:52:08.796
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17059], [0x0AF7B85A0], [0x0AF7B8E38], [0x0BC22B3E0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2558
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2771
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_IREFRESH", line 685
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REFRESH", line 195
ORA-06512: at line 1 **

Comment: @NiteshKumar - An ORA-00600 error is an internal Oracle error.  Have you looked up the particular arguments in the My Oracle Support ORA-00600 lookup tool?  There is a good chance that there is a patch (or patchset) that you will need to apply to resolve the issue.